# Datatable.GetErrors returning incorrect datarows

Tags: c#, database, datatable, dataset, enterprise-library

I am using a datatable to insert records in the database, making use of the Data Block of the Enterprise Library.

As you will see in the code below, I issue a UpdateDataSet on the dataset and then look for errors in the DataTable, extracting the offending datarows. I have to generate a report on these erroneous records.

For testing I have added one row which will conform to the database and get inserted, added another which violates a FK constraint.

```
 DbCommand command = _database.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_Simple_Insert");
            _database.AddInParameter(command, "JobID", DbType.Int32, "JobID", DataRowVersion.Current);
            ...
            ...
            ...

            int rowsaffected = _database.UpdateDataSet(dataSet, tableName, command, null, null, UpdateBehavior.Continue, batchSize); // batchsize is 1000

            LogMessage("SaveBatch", string.Format("BatchCount: {0}, AffectedRows: {1}", dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count, rowsaffected), Level.Info);

            if (dataSet.Tables[tableName].HasErrors)
            {
                DataRow[] rows = dataSet.Tables[tableName].GetErrors();
                LogMessage("SaveBatch", string.Format("Errors: {0}", rows.Length), Level.Debug);
            }
```

When I look at the Datarow returned from the GetErrors method, it is actually the one which got inserted in the database.

When I have just the erroneous row in the dataset, it returns the correct row in the errors.

I am not certain if this because of the Enterprise library or something else. One thing is for sure this is not how it should be.

Comment: How do you know that it's the wrong row? Have you used the debugger since you're not logging it.

Comment: The same with unlimited batch-size (0)? Also check it before you update.

Comment: The same result with batch size (0). Before the update it shows no errors. Is there anything else I can try, or maybe a totally different approach to achieve the same task?